# How to Append to rather than overwrite single table using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, table

The code thus far works to create multiple output files, but I'd like to set it up so that the data is all exported onto a single table across multiple rows.  The issue is I believe with the part in bold below:

```
#script to calculate home range overlap (hectares) between two individuals

# import modules
import arcpy
import time
import os
#import tabletoexcel
arcpy.ImportToolbox("xxx\Additional Conversion - Generic Tools.tbx")

from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True


# local variables

#hardcode test
ou1 = r"xxx\bbmmAnsPoly90.shp"
arcpy.env.workspace = r"xxx\ninety"
outputfolder = r"xxx\ninety\test"
#logfile = r"xxx\ansoverlap.txt"
#ou1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
#outputfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
#int_output_Statistics = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
logfile = outputfolder + "\\" + ou1 + "_" + "overlaps.txt"
print logfile

try:
    # process: intersect
    #intersect_analysis (in_features, out_feature_class, {join_attributes}, {cluster_tolerance}, {output_type})
    ou2s = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

    for ou2 in ou2s:  
        fcname1 = arcpy.Describe(ou1).basename
        fcname2 = arcpy.Describe(ou2).basename
        **int_output = os.path.join(outputfolder, str(fcname1 + fcname2) + ".shp")
        #int_output = os.path.join(outputfolder, str(fcname1) + "_overlaps.shp")
        int_output_Statistics = r"xxx\Default.gdb" + "\\" + str(fcname1 + fcname2)
        #int_output_Statistics = r"xxx\Default.gdb" + "\\" + str(fcname1) + "_overlaps"**
        excel_output = outputfolder + "\\" + str(fcname1 + fcname2)  
        #excel_output = outputfolder + "\\" + str(fcname1) + "_overlaps"

        logfile = outputfolder + "\\" + fcname1 + "_" + "overlaps.txt"
        if arcpy.Exists(logfile):
            f = open(logfile, "a")
        else:
            f = open(logfile, "w")    

        f.write(time.strftime('%c'))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("------------------------------")
        f.write("\n")

        arcpy.analysis.Intersect([ou1, ou2], int_output)
        f.write("\n" + "Calculating home range overlap between " + fcname1 + " & " + fcname2)
        print "Calculating home range overlap between " + fcname1 + " & " + fcname2

        # process: add field
        arcpy.management.AddField(int_output, "Overlap", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
        f.write("\n" + "Adding \"Overlap\" field to " + int_output)
        print "Adding \"Overlap\" field to " + int_output

        # process: calculate field
        arcpy.management.CalculateField(int_output, "Overlap", "!shape.area@HECTARES!", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
        f.write("\n" + "Calculating geometry of overlap between " + fcname1 + " " + fcname2)
        print "Calculating geometry of overlap between " + fcname1 + " " + fcname2

        # process: delete identical
        arcpy.management.DeleteIdentical(int_output, "Overlap", "", "0")
        f.write("\n" + "Deleting identical values from \"Overlap\" field")
        print "Deleting identical values from \"Overlap\" field"

        # process: summary statistics
        f.write("\n" + "Determine overlap value in hectares")
        print "Determine overlap value in hectares"

        arcpy.analysis.Statistics(int_output, int_output_Statistics, "Overlap SUM", "")
        arcpy.management.AddField(int_output_Statistics, 'orangutan1', 'TEXT')
        arcpy.management.AddField(int_output_Statistics, 'isopleth1', 'DOUBLE')
        arcpy.management.AddField(int_output_Statistics, 'orangutan2', 'TEXT')
        arcpy.management.AddField(int_output_Statistics, 'isopleth2', 'DOUBLE')

        search1 = arcpy.SearchCursor(ou1)
        for scrap in search1:
            ou1_name = scrap.getValue("ou")
            ou1_iso = scrap.getValue("iso")

        search2 = arcpy.SearchCursor(ou2)
        for scrap in search2:
            ou2_name = scrap.getValue("ou")
            ou2_iso = scrap.getValue("iso")
            #row_values = [(scrap.getValue("ou"), scrap.getValue("iso"))]

        cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(int_output_Statistics)

        for row in cursor:
            row.setValue("orangutan1", ou1_name)
            row.setValue("orangutan2", ou2_name)
            row.setValue("isopleth1", ou1_iso)
            row.setValue("isopleth2", ou2_iso)
            cursor.updateRow(row)


        f.write("\n" + "Writing to:" + " " + int_output_Statistics)

        #export_to_xls(dataset, output):
        arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion2(int_output_Statistics, excel_output, "XLS")
        print "Writing to excel file"
        f.write("\n" + "Writing to excel file:" + " " + excel_output)
        f.write("\n" + "------------------------------")
        f.write ("\n")




    f.close



except Exception, e:
    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print e.message
```

So, is there a method (perhaps similar to f = open(logfile, "a" ?), whereby I could append to rather than overwrite a table?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one idea:
arcpy.Append_management will append things but they have to be similar. So feature classes append to feature classes, tables to tables.  I recently wrote a script where I had to export my FC to a scratch (temporary) table using CopyRows and then append that table to a big "collector" table. You could do something similar in a geodatabase and export the final table to excel.

Answer (score 1):

You have used both a SearchCursor and an UpdateCursor in your code but to write additional rows to a table the type of cursor to use is an **[InsertCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000002z000000)**.